# Docker cant find file location in windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a software for predicting hemorrhage volume on brain CT in docker: https://github.com/msharrock/deepbleed

I created a "deepbleed" folder in my `D:\` drive on windows, and ran `docker pull msharrock/deepbleed` command after I cd'd inside that directory. The pull was successful and I can see the container in my docker desktop app.

Then I went on and created an `indir` and `outdir` folder as instructed in documentation; placed my CT file for prediction in the `indir` folder.

The readme tells me to run this command next:

```
docker run -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v /path/to/data:/data/
```

So I have run the following commands, but I get "no such file or directory" for all of them:

```
docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v pwd/deepbleed/indir:outdir

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v ~/deepbleed/indir:/outdir/

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v /mnt/d/deepbleed/indir:/outdir/

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v /d/deepbleed/indir:/outdir

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v "$(& "D:\deepbleed\indir" "$(pwd)")":/outdir

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v /indir/:/outdir/

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v //d:/deepbleed/indir://d:/deepbleed/outdir/

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v //d/deepbleed/indir://d/deepbleed/outdir/

docker run --rm -it msharrock/deepbleed bash -v //d/deepbleed/indir:/outdir/
```

My docker is running on a wsl2 based engine in windows 10, the hyper-v folders for disks and virtual machines are located on my `d:` drive.

What do I need to do to get this running?

Comment: does it work if you put the `-v hostpath:guestpath` before the `bash` argument?

Comment: Also, are you running these docker commands from the wsl2 prompt or from powershell or cmd?

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much!
I am using powershell, and when i did what you said, i guess it somehow ran the app but nothing happened, right now it seems i am in the docker container root@0b3c1ba9b7f9:/build# (it changed from PS C:\Users\win10> to this now)

Comment: If you are in powershell, then I think your `hostpath` should be a windows path like `'d:/blah'` and your guest path will be a linux path in the container like `/outdir`. You ended up in the container because that's all the command does: run `bash` so you are in the container. I'm guessing they expect you to run the scripts manually from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this (just using one of your items in the list for this example to give you the idea):

```
docker run -rm -it -v /mnt/d/deepbleed/indir:/outdir msharrock/deepbleed bash
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for the answer. 
After i typed it in it seems i am in the docker container terminal now. but nothing else happened.

i then typed "python predict.py --verbose --indir ./indir --outdir ./outdir --weights weights" as it suggests i would do with normal python installation, but now it says: python: can't open file 'predict.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @ŞiyarBahadır that means you did it right and are now in the container, at the bash prompt. Make sure you're in the directory that has `predict.py` in it before running that command.